# lodash Left Join two objects

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, lodash

```
var data = [{LearnerId:6362, ColName:AETY10, Value:9, Subject:E+, LookupId:37}]
var subs = [{LookupId:4, Name:Art},{LookupId:37, Name:Maths}]

var merged = _.merge(_.keyBy(data,'LookupId'), _.keyBy(subs, 'LookupId'));
var mapped = _.values(merged);
```

But this doesn't return the array as left join so I want it appear as:

```
var mapped = [{LearnerId:6362, ColName:AETY10, Value:9, Subject:E+, LookupId:37,Name:Maths}]
```

Is this possible in Lodash?

Comment: please add valid data. is `subs` an array?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes they are both arrays. sorry not very well demonstrated in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `lodash`, you could take a function which performs an outer join with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for wanted key and returns an array with new object with additional properties.

```js
var outerjoin = (data, outer, key) => {
        const lookup = new Map(subs.map(o => [o[key], o]));
        return data.map(o => ({ ...o, ...lookup.get(o[key]) }));
    },
    data = [{ LearnerId: 6362, ColName:'AETY10', Value: 9, Subject: 'E+', LookupId: 37 }],
    subs = [{ LookupId: 4, Name: 'Art' }, { LookupId: 37, Name: 'Maths' }],
    merged = outerjoin(data, subs, 'LookupId');

console.log(merged);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can't get this working - Using this in Google App Script.

Comment: @DavidDraper Don't think there's anything unique in apps script to not work. Underneath, it's a full blown v8 engine. Explain what doesn't work or why you think it isn't working.

Comment: @TheMaster because its returning Null.

Comment: @NinaScholz its returning null.

Comment: No it skips and produces Null.

Comment: sorry. can not help.

Comment: @DavidDraper Clear everything. Copy paste this script only inside a function named `myFunction`. Run `myFunction`. See view> executions